# Translational invariance clarification.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

The question and its solution are given below (note you have to replace $n$ in the solution by $c$):

> [image]
>   [image]

My question is why $c$ (or $n$ as in the solution) is clearly translation invariant? could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: This measure is actually invariant for any bijection of $\mathbb R$ onto itself. Translations are an example of such bijections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $r\in\mathbb R$ and $E\subseteq R$ then a bijection $E\mapsto r+E:=\{r+x\mid x\in E\}$ exists that is prescribed by $x\mapsto r+x$.

Based on this it can be concluded directly that

- $E$ has infinitely many members $\iff r+E$ has infinitely many members.
- $E$ has $n$ elements  $\iff r+E$ has $n$ elements (where $n$ is a positive integer).
- $E=\varnothing\iff r+E=\varnothing$.

This comes to the same as $c(E)=c(r+E)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is an infinite set then $\{a+x: a \in A\}$ is also an infinite set fro any real number $x$. If $A$ is a finite set then $\{a+x: a \in A\}$ is also a finite set and has the same number of elements as $A$. Hence $c(A+x)=c(A)$.